# Output of H5 and JSON model is different

Tags: javascript, python, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have trained Keras model for sign language classification which is working well in python.
However, I need to implement it in the browser side. So I am using tensorflow js for that purpose.

I am able to load the model in browser but the problem is that prediction is inaccurate.
I am taking input from webcam. and on button click I am storing the webcam input in a canvas and then passing canvas to tf.browser.fromPixels
In python version it is working almost perfect but in browser side it is not able to correctly predict a single label. Here is the code of my index.html file

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebRTC: Still photo capture demo</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" media="all"> -->
    <script src="capture.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contentarea">
    <h1>
        MDN - WebRTC: Still photo capture demo
    </h1>
    <p>
        This example demonstrates how to set up a media stream using your built-in webcam, fetch an image from that stream, and create a PNG using that image.
    </p>
  <div class="camera">
    <video width="64px" height="64px" id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button> 
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
  <div class="output">
    <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box."> 
  </div>
    <p>
        Visit our article <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos"> Taking still photos with WebRTC</a> to learn more about the technologies used here.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is capture.js file

```
(function () {
  // The width and height of the captured photo. We will set the
  // width to the value defined here, but the height will be
  // calculated based on the aspect ratio of the input stream.

  var width = 64; // We will scale the photo width to this
  var height = 64; // This will be computed based on the input stream

  // |streaming| indicates whether or not we're currently streaming
  // video from the camera. Obviously, we start at false.

  var streaming = false;

  // The various HTML elements we need to configure or control. These
  // will be set by the startup() function.

  var video = null;
  var canvas = null;
  var photo = null;
  var startbutton = null;

  function startup() {
    video = document.getElementById("video");
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    photo = document.getElementById("photo");
    startbutton = document.getElementById("startbutton");

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: {
          width: { min: 64, ideal: 64, max: 64 },
          height: { min: 64, ideal: 64, max: 64 },
        },
        audio: false,
      })
      .then(function (stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
      });

    video.addEventListener(
      "canplay",
      function (ev) {
        if (!streaming) {
          height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

          // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
          // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.

          if (isNaN(height)) {
            height = width / (4 / 3);
          }

          video.setAttribute("width", width);
          video.setAttribute("height", height);
          canvas.setAttribute("width", 64);
          canvas.setAttribute("height", 64);
          streaming = true;
        }
      },
      false
    );

    startbutton.addEventListener(
      "click",
      function (ev) {
        takepicture();
        ev.preventDefault();
      },
      false
    );

    clearphoto();
  }

  // Fill the photo with an indication that none has been
  // captured.

  function clearphoto() {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    photo.setAttribute("src", data);
  }

  // Capture a photo by fetching the current contents of the video
  // and drawing it into a canvas, then converting that to a PNG
  // format data URL. By drawing it on an offscreen canvas and then
  // drawing that to the screen, we can change its size and/or apply
  // other changes before drawing it.

  function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (width && height) {
      canvas.width = 64;
      canvas.height = 64;
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 64, 64);

      var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      photo.setAttribute("src", data);
      classifyVideo();
    } else {
      clearphoto();
    }
  }
  //tfjs

  const opclasses = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i",
    "j",
    "k",
    "l",
    "m",
    "n",
    "o",
    "p",
    "q",
    "r",
    "s",
    "t",
    "u",
    "v",
    "w",
    "x",
    "y",
    "z",
    "del",
    "nothing",
    "space",
  ];
  let imageModelURL = "./model.json";
  //let imageee = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
  let model;
  async function tensorFlow() {
    console.log("loading model");

    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
      console.log("dom not loaded");
    }

    model = await tf.loadLayersModel(imageModelURL);
    //classifyVideo();
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", run);
  function run() {
    console.log("DOM Content Loaded");
    tensorFlow();
  }
  async function classifyVideo() {
    // console.log("classifying video");
    // console.log(tf);
    // console.log(tf.browser);
    // console.log(tf.browser.fromPixel);
    let example = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas);

    let prediction = await model.predict(example.expandDims(0)).data();

    let top5 = Array.from(prediction)
      .map(function (p, i) {
        return {
          probability: p,
          classNameIndex: i,
        };
      })
      .sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.probability - a.probability;
      })
      .slice(0, 5);
    model.summary();

    console.log(opclasses[top5[0].classNameIndex]);
    let toast = document.getElementById("Toast");
    toast.innerHTML = opclasses[top5[0].classNameIndex];

    // classifyVideo();
  }

  // Set up our event listener to run the startup process
  // once loading is complete.
  window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
})();
```

I am not sure why is this happening. i am beginner In this field. Thanks for your help